# Create a rand binary string of variable length

Tags: excel, binary, decimal

So I am using 2 rand features, the first is a rand that generates a 4 to 19 value for how many bits there will be in the second one.

the second one needs to then create a random binary string (in a single cell, not trying to make a lot of cells on my already large project) equal to the length the first one said.

For example there are 5 cells for each, the first row says 4,14,6,8,9 for the values using RAND. **for example =RAND()*(19-4)+4**

Then the next one would need to generate a result similar to this:
0110,10000111011001,000011,10101010,110011001

My problem is generating the longer line using =dec2bin(ROUND(RAND()*(2^B10-1)+1,0),B10)   **B10 is the first cell indicating length**

I get a lot of results that just won't post with a #NUM error. It seems 10 bits is the maximum? Is there a way around this without using a LOT of cells? I am going to hit my laptops computational capabilities on this whole thing and really am trying to keep the amount of formulas down.

Thanks all in advance.

=ROUND(RAND()*(2^B10-1)+1,0) does not work when b10 is greater than 10...

Comment: Probably this might work using `BASE()` ==> `=BASE(ROUND(RAND()*(2^B10-1)+1,0),2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first choice would be to use [Randbetween](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randbetween-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685) and [Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/base-function-2ef61411-aee9-4f29-a811-1c42456c6342) if these are available to you.

To generate the number of digits:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(4,19)
```

then (similar to what @Mayukh Bhattacharya has suggested) to generate the random binary number:

```
=BASE(RANDBETWEEN(0,2^A2-1),2,A2)
```

[image]

If you are using an old version of Excel and have to use dec2bin and rand, I can add this to my post.